# Using raspistill with parameter -tl and -a produces the same date each time

Tags: camera, raspicam

According to the [documentation of the camera module](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/camera.md) you can use the parameter `-tl` to take a picture every `x` time, thus, with the parameter `-a`, you can write in the image the date and the time, specifically with `-a 12`.

It works with the first image but with the rest of images taked the date and time are always the same. I use raspistill in this way.

```
raspistill -w 640 -h 480 -vf -q 10 -o /home/pi/development/node_webserver/public/images/pic.jpg -tl 200 -t 9999999 -th 0:0:0 -a 12 -n &
```

Take picture every 200 ms but in all the version of the pic I obtain the same date and time.